# How to save a collection for later use in Magento?

Tags: magento, cron, registry

I want to write a cronjob in Magento that loads a product collection following certain parameters and saves it somewhere I can use in a cms/page.

My first approach was to use Magento's registry, but that doesn't work, ie a simple

```
Mage::register('label',$product_collection);
```

... doesn't work, as it seems "label" is not available in Mage::registry in my PHTML file...

Can someone point me in the right direction?  Is this the correct approach? If so, how to make it work; if not, how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why can't you just load the collection on the CMS page itself? I've missed the point why do you need that cron job in the first place

Comment: I want a product page to display products from a specific category on a random order that changes daily, so I need to generate the collection and ensure it will remain in that particular order throughout the day.  I also need layered navigation to be activated as well.

Comment: Thanks for explanations @Paulo, but I still don't see the point of storing the entire collection in cache. You can just introduce the random value that would be changed each day, and by which you'll decide what sorting you're using today. And load your collection in the CMS Page itself... but I may still not understand the real purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Mage::register will not get you where you want to go. The Mage registry keys are saved in the memory of the running PHP script, so it is scoped to the page request that is running the PHP code and therefor not shared between cron and your PHTML file.

In order to accomplish what you're looking for, you would need to cache the collection to persistent storage, such as hard-disk or Memcache. You may have to call the load() function specifically before caching, like so:

```
<?php
// ...
// ... Somewhere in your cron script
$product_collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('some_field', 'some_value');
$product_collection->load(); // Magento kind of "lazy-loads" its data, so
                             // without this, you might not save yourself
                             // from executing MySQL code in the PHTML

// Serialize the data so it can be saved to cache as a string
$cacheData = serialize($product_collection);

$cacheKey = 'some sort of unique cache key';

// Save the serialized collection to the cache (defined in app/etc/local.xml)
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->save($cacheData, $cacheKey);
```

Then, in your PHTML file try:

```
<?php
// ...
$cacheKey = 'same unique cache key set in the cron script';

// Load the collection from cache
$product_collection = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->load($cacheKey);

// I'm not sure if Magento will auto-unserialize your object, so if
// the cache gives us a string, then we will do it ourselves
if ( is_string($product_collection) ) {
    $product_collection = unserialize($product_collectoin);
}

// ...
```

See http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/240836

Comment: Good points! Thanks for the tips.  I was on the way to use serialize, but was unable to figure out the cache part!

Comment: json would be less space consuming in case of big amount of data. Also it will be better to save each item of the collection separately ( and only the getData() content ) and the on load populate the item collection with these datas